# What makes an SQLite table locked when the database is first opened?

Tags: sqlite, locking

Under what circumstances can a table be locked when the database is first opened?

My program does:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
CREATE TABLE
INSERT INTO (multiple times)
SELECT * (for each row)
```

Run it once and it works perfectly. Run it twice and the DROP TABLE triggers the error:

```
SQLITE_LOCKED, database table is locked
```

Delete the database and run it again and it works. Just once.

Nothing in the documentation tells me how a table can be locked when the database is first opened. I'm using the raw C interface on Windows, so what can I be doing wrong?

---

The code is actually written in C#, but uses Interop to call the C API directly.
The database open code looks like this. No open flags are used.

```
LastResult = (Result)sqlite3_open(path, out _dbhandle);
```

Comment: Do you mean that you run your application once, then the application exists and you run it again - then the error happens?

Comment: Why are you using shared-cache mode?

Comment: @Googie: Correct. And it's not because of a Windows lock on the database file -- I checked.

Comment: @CL.: Am I? What does the question even mean?

Comment: Please show your `sqlite3_open()` call(s), and explain why you're using the flag(s) you're using.

Comment: @CL.: See edit. No flags, just the basic sql_open().

Comment: Sorry, I've notices that SQLITE_LOCKED can also happen without shared-cache mode. Anyway, there is a problem with open cursors. Show your code.

Comment: @CL.: Not really possible: the app is around 10KLOC. It generates SQL code on the fly. See andl.org for what it does. If you have any idea of how a database can stay locked when it's closed, please submit an answer.